# Assetic and Twig default filter

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

In order to take advantage of Assetic in production environment I'm translating asset usage like:

```
<img class="vcenter" src="{{ asset('img/LicenseBundle/icons/license_icon.png') }}"/>
```

to

```
{% image '@ManagerLicenseBundle/Resources/public/img/icons/license_icon.png' %}
    <img class="vcenter" src="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endimage %}
```

but how, if possible, can I translate something like this (defining a default fallback):

```
<img class="vcenter" src="{{ asset(license.type.urlLogo)|default( asset('img/LicenseBundle/icons/license_icon.png')) }}"/>
```

**other than** writing a bunch of

```
{% if license is defined and not empty and blablabla and license.type is defined and blablaomgthistakesforever %}
    {% image license.type.urlLogo %}
        <img class="vcenter" src="{{ asset_url }}"/>
    {% endimage %}
{% else %}
     {% image license.type.urlLogo %}
        <img class="vcenter" src="{{ asset_url }}"/>
    {% endimage %}
{% endif %}
```

which, done for every image is just a chore and makes me want to cry.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<img class="vcenter" src="{{
    asset(license.type.urlLogo|default('img/LicenseBundle/icons/license_icon.png'))
}}"/>
```

instead of

```
<img class="vcenter" src="{{
    asset(license.type.urlLogo)|default( asset('img/LicenseBundle/icons/license_icon.png'))
}}"/>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. What I wrote works, but I would like to use the {% image %} tag to pass it through assetic, but also have the "default" functionality.